# Int to date in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-convert

I try to convert the column `[policyeffective_date]` which looks like `YYYYMMDD` (for example `20190430`) into a date in SQL Server.

I tried a few solutions find on the forum, but none worked. Currently I have the following code and errors:

```
SELECT 
    CONVERT(DATETIME, policyeffective_date, 104) AS test 
FROM 
    [DATAWAREHOUSE].[dbo].[blabla]
```

Error:

> Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime.

I also tried:

```
SELECT 
    CONVERT(DATE, CONVERT(NVARCHAR(8), policyeffective_date), 104)    
FROM 
    [DATAWAREHOUSE].[dbo].[blabla]
```

Error:

> Operand type clash: int is incompatible with date

Thank you for your help

Comment: This works for me: DECLARE @policyeffective_date int = 20201201; SELECT convert(date, convert(nvarchar(8),  @policyeffective_date), 104) ;

Comment: Are you sure the values are all in YYYYMMDD format?

Comment: You can use the left() to get the string of the int which will convert    Select try_convert(date,left(20190430,8))

Comment: And now you will discover why storing dates as numbers (or strings) is a bad idea.

Comment: Whose smart idea was it to store date as `INT`?  Date is meant to be stored as `DATETIME` type, not `INT`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This works for me in SQL Server 2017:

```
select cast(cast(20190430 as nvarchar) as DATE) AS DateResult
```

Output:

```
DateResult
2019-04-30
```

Answer (score 1):

You would seem to have bad data in the column.  Given that you are getting a run-time error and not a compile-time error, the types seem correct.

The simplest solution is `try_convert()`:

```
SELECT try_convert(datetime, policyeffective_date, 104) AS test 
FROM [DATAWAREHOUSE].[dbo].[blabla];
```

But to find the problem, you can use:

```
SELECT policyeffective_date
FROM [DATAWAREHOUSE].[dbo].[blabla]
WHERE try_convert(datetime, policyeffective_date, 104) IS NULL AND
      policyeffective_date IS NOT NULL
```